# Windows hard crashing after some time playing videogames (no BSOD) [Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, crash, gaming

I decided to format my computer (which was working fine) to perform a clean install of Windows 10 (was using Windows 7). Now everytime I start playing a game, after about 15 minutes or so, it'll just crash while repeating the audio, requiring a hard reset. If I don't open a videogame I can use it just fine, watch videos, do video-editing.

What I did do:

- Checked the temperature, everything is below 35C° even at the time it crashes.
- Did a memory test using memtest86, everything was fine.
- Updated all my drivers using DriverBooster PRO.
- Did a chkdsk, everything also seems to be fine.

My hardware stuff:

AMD-FX8350 Processor

970A-D3P Mainboard

8Gb DDR3 RAM Memory Stick

Radeon RX480+ Nitro GPU

1TB HDD

About the only thing I haven't tried doing was reverting it back to Windows 7, but I want to keep Windows 10, since a lot of the programs I use are being updated exclusively to it. But I'm stumped, it was working fine before formating and installing the new Windows.

Thanks for any assistance you guys might be able to give me, I'm pretty lost at this point!

Comment: Have you tried moving the video card to a different PCI-E slot?

Answer (score -1):

I assume all drivers are updated? That's where I'd start, especially the graphics card. AMD makes it easy to find the correct one. http://www.sapphiretech.com/download.asp?lang=eng

Comment: I think they are, Radeon Settings (the program that comes with the driver) says everything is up to date on my gpu and chipsets wise. As for the rest, I used a program called DriverBooster PRO to auto-update all of my drivers and the program also says everything is up to date.

Comment: Still on general stuff - reseat RAM and anything in slots. For the heck of it, you could drain any flea power. Remove the CMOS battery and the power cable and hold the power button down. Then put the battery and power cable back and try the game again.

Comment: That is annoying that it takes 15 minutes to test/confirm anything. It's always 15 minutes? Anything in Event Viewer? I assume not.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine it has to be something to do with the ammount of resources games use over time or something? Because I can even edit videos without it happening. But I'll follow your instructions and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: If it's not a full-screen game (c'mon David!) you can even keep Task Manager up to watch the RAM usage maybe. I'm suspecting there's a hardware problem, not just resource depletion. Yes, looking forward to getting to an update.

Comment: Have you checked event viewer it gives you the accurate reason why your windows crashed

Comment: I tried everything you suggested to no avail David. Also, did put my games on windowed and tried checking the resource usage. Everything seems fine, I took a photo of my screen with my phone when it did crash (It just stays in the same screen), wonder if you smart people can glean anything from it! http://i.imgur.com/qtFtF3f.jpg

Comment: Elie, I just checked the event viewer but I'm not entirely sure what to look for. I did see some stuff on the Critical tab underneath Summary of Administrative Events. One was ID 404 Task Scheduler, but the other one is a ID 41 Kernel-Power, and the occurrence of that one sorta seems to match the ammount of times I have crashed. Maybe that's it? Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: Event Viewer will only catch it if Windows is running when the event occurs. The event is crashing Windows so the only event associated will likely be "last shutdown was unexpected." Something in hardware is crashing. After reset, reseat, the next step is replace. I don't know that any of us, as PC owners, would have access to debug at the component level but that is what you would need to determine what is going bad. That's my answer but certainly not a solution. I'm annoyed at the downvote for trying to help but I understand you're leaving unsatisfied at the result.